# Update object value for view only

Tags: django, python-3.x

So i have an array of objects that have a role. each role has underscores for spaces. Now i know the best way in most cases would be to simply change the value in the database to the correct format but i need it to have spaces.

So instead of the value to look like this:

```
role: this_is_my_role
```

I need it to look like this:

```
role: this is my role
```

but only for my view. I've tried the following but it does not work.

```
def view_info(request):
    device = Device.objects
    for item in device:
        item.role = item.role.replace('_', ' ')

    return render(request, 'table_view.html', {'device': device})
```

please note, i **do not** want to change the actual value in the database. I only want to change the value before rendering the template.

Comment: What is rendering now?

Comment: It just shows the value as if the loop wasn't there.

Comment: Did actually loop executed? Try print statement or debug

Comment: well it must do right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really the right approach. You have data in one format and you want to display it in another format. You can either do this in the template itself, with a custom template filter, or provide a property on the model which outputs the converted data. The second is probably the easiest:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def role_output(self):
        return self.role.replace('_', ' ')
```

Now you can simply pass the queryset to the template, and there do `{{ device.role_output }}` to get your converted value.